# Rspec how to test in inject method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method that looks like this:

```
  def self.average_top_level_comments_leaders
    top_level_comment_count = CrucibleComment.group(:user_id).where(parent_comment_id: nil).order('count_all DESC').count
    code_review_assigned_count = Reviewer.group(:user_id).order('count_all DESC').count

    division_result = top_level_comment_count.inject({}) do |result, item|
      id = item.first #id =12
      count = item.last #value = 57
      if (count && code_review_assigned_count[id]) 
        result[id] = (count/ code_review_assigned_count[id]).round(2) 
        #result[12] = 57/12 = 3.3, => {12, 3.3}
      end
      result 
    end
  end
```

This method returns a hash with the IDs as keys and the results of the division as the values.

I have successfully tested top_level_comment_count and code_review_assigned count, but I am having trouble figuring out how I can test the 4 other things that are in the do block:

```
.first, .last, .round(2), result
```

I am trying to test .first and this is what I have so far:

```
describe '#average_top_level_comments_leaders' do
    subject { User.average_top_level_comments_leaders}

    let(:avg_top_level_comments) { double }
    let(:code_review_count) { double }
    let(:item) { double( {id: 12}) }

    context 'when getting the comment count succeeds ' do
      before do
        allow(CrucibleComment).to receive(:group).with(:user_id).and_return(avg_top_level_comments)
        allow(avg_top_level_comments).to receive(:where).with(parent_comment_id: nil).and_return(avg_top_level_comments)
        allow(avg_top_level_comments).to receive(:order).with('count_all DESC').and_return(avg_top_level_comments)
        allow(avg_top_level_comments).to receive(:count).and_return(avg_top_level_comments)

        allow(avg_top_level_comments).to receive(:inject).and_return(avg_top_level_comments)
        allow(item).to receive(:first).and_return(item)

        allow(Reviewer).to receive(:group).with(:user_id).and_return(code_review_count)
        allow(code_review_count).to receive(:order).with('count_all DESC').and_return(code_review_count)
        allow(code_review_count).to receive(:count).and_return(code_review_count)
        allow(code_review_count).to receive(:round).with(2).and_return(code_review_count)
      end

      it 'and the correct parameters are called' do
        expect(CrucibleComment).to receive(:group).with(:user_id)
        subject
      end

      it 'and comment count is calling descending correctly' do
        expect(avg_top_level_comments).to receive(:order).with('count_all DESC')
        subject
      end

      it 'item gets the first result' do
        expect(item).to receive(:first)
        subject
      end
    end
  end
```

I cannot get the last it statement to pass. I am trying to expect(item).to receive(:first), but it says this in the error:

Failure/Error: expect(item).to receive(:first)
       (Double).first(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments

Any idea why this is not passing? The other two its are passing

Comment: IMHO you're tests are too tightly coupled. Instead of all the stubbing, setup the data so that the call returns what you know it should and ensure it does. You don't want your test to fail simply because I changed `round` to something equivalent (ie. `(... + 0.5).floor` or something).

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Now that I think about it I actutally just want to test "result" How can I test that?

Answer (score 2):

The `item` double is never used in the test, so when it reaches:

```
expect(item).to receive(:first)
```

it fails.

If you were expecting the `item` double to be used within the `inject` block here:

```
division_result = top_level_comment_count.inject({}) do |result, item|
```

merely by virtue of it having the same name, it doesn't work that way. You'd need to define a method on the `avg_top_level_comments` double that returns the `item` double when `inject` is called.

But, you shouldn't do that. Throw all of this out and use real model instances for the test. It will be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: How can I do real model instances for this test? Can you give an example?

Comment: Create rows in the test database, either with fixtures or factories, and just let the scopes find them. It does take work, and it will be slower, but you will have more confidence in the final result.

Comment: I cannot use the database in this case. It has to be all mocking. Is this possible?

Comment: I hesitate to ask, but, why can you not use the database? As to whether it is possible to mock it all out, yes, anything is possible with Ruby! But if you are not able to use a test database to test your app, I'd say that is the real elephant in the room.